# Breaking a long string into individual words to enter into Binary Tree

Tags: java, string, text-files

So I am currently reading a text file into my program which is suppose to be broken up into individual words and stored in a binary tree.

So far I have converted my text file into a single string and then modified that string to remove all punctuation and make everything lowercase (i am instructed to do so). I am having trouble finding a way to now break up my massive string into individual words which I then need to insert into a binary tree.

here is my code

```
public class Tester {

//Start the program
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Tester run = new Tester();
    run.it();

}

//run Program step by step
public void it() throws FileNotFoundException { 

    BTree theTree = new BTree();
    this.readInFile();

    theTree.print();

}

//Read file into string
public String readInFile() throws FileNotFoundException {


    String myFile = "";
    int numWords = 0;

    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(new File("Dracula.txt"));

    while(myScan.hasNext() == true) {

        myFile += myScan.nextLine();

    }

    return myFile;

}

//delete punctuation make all letters lowercase
public String stripPunctuation(String myFile) {

    myFile.replace('.', ' ');
    myFile.replace(',', ' ');
    myFile.replace('!', ' ');
    myFile.replace('?', ' ');
    myFile.replace('(', ' ');
    myFile.replace(')', ' ');
    myFile.replace('"', ' ');
    myFile.replace('[', ' ');
    myFile.replace(']', ' ');
    myFile.toLowerCase();
    return myFile;

}

//here is where i want to break up the string and add each word to my binary tree
public BTree fillTree(String myFile) {

    BTree thisTree = new BTree();

    while()

    return thisTree;

}

}
```

I was thinking a while loop might help but I'm not sure how to scan a string char by char to break it apart correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
```

`split()` uses a regex to determine what part of the input is the delimiter. The regex `\s+` means "1 or more whitespace characters".

Also, you have a bug in your code. This line:

```
myFile += myScan.nextLine();
```

Will have the effect of concatenating the last word of a line with the first word of the next line. The minimum change to fix this would be:

```
myFile += myScan.nextLine() + " ";
```